# How to draw a line in arkit based on CLLocation in iOS Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, mapbox, arkit

I am trying to use `ARKit` for outdoor navigation. I have used `mapbox` for AR navigation and used `mapboxarkit` and `mapboxDirection` cocoapods.

The nodes are shown as paths. I am able to show paths as dotted shperes or planes but am not able show them as lines. Here are my output screenshots

This is the node, which I have tried to show as a line breaking and tried to adjust `scnbox` to be straight and show as a line:
[image: This is the node, which I have tried to show as a line breaking and tried to adjust <code>scnbox</code> to be straight and show as a line].

This is the result I expect:

[image: I want an AR line like this.]

Here is the code I have tried so far - Here is the code to add an AR annotation and AR line.

```
if let route = routes?.first, let leg = route.legs.first {
    var polyline = [CLLocationCoordinate2D]()

    // Add an AR node and map view annotation for every defined "step" in the route
    for step in leg.steps {
        let coordinate = step.coordinates!.first!
        polyline.append(coordinate)
        let stepLocation = CLLocation(latitude: coordinate.latitude, longitude: coordinate.longitude)

        // Update feature collection for map view
        self.updateShapeCollectionFeature(&self.waypointShapeCollectionFeature, with: stepLocation, typeKey: "waypoint-type", typeAttribute: "big")

        // Add an AR node
        let annotation = Annotation(location: stepLocation, calloutImage: self.calloutImage(for: step.description))
        annotationsToAdd.append(annotation)
    }

    let metersPerNode: CLLocationDistance = 1
    let turfPolyline = Polyline(polyline)

    // Walk the route line and add a small AR node and map view annotation every metersPerNode
    for i in stride(from: metersPerNode, to: turfPolyline.distance() - metersPerNode, by: metersPerNode) {            
        // Use Turf to find the coordinate of each incremented distance along the polyline
        if let nextCoordinate = turfPolyline.coordinateFromStart(distance: i) {
            let interpolatedStepLocation = CLLocation(latitude: nextCoordinate.latitude, longitude: nextCoordinate.longitude)

            // Update feature collection for map view
            self.updateShapeCollectionFeature(&self.waypointShapeCollectionFeature, with: interpolatedStepLocation, typeKey: "waypoint-type", typeAttribute: "small")

            // Add an AR node
            let annotation = Annotation(location: interpolatedStepLocation, calloutImage: nil)
            annotationsToAdd.append(annotation)
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the code for creating a `scnplane`:

```
func createLightBulbNode() -> SCNNode {
    let lightBulbNode = collada2SCNNode(filepath: "art.scnassets/cubeSolid.dae")

    lightBulbNode.position = SCNVector3(0, -0.5, 0)

    return lightBulbNode
}

func collada2SCNNode(filepath:String) -> SCNNode {
    let node = SCNNode()
    let scene = SCNScene(named: filepath, inDirectory: nil, options: [SCNSceneSource.LoadingOption.animationImportPolicy: SCNSceneSource.AnimationImportPolicy.doNotPlay])
    let nodeArray = scene!.rootNode.childNodes
    for childNode in nodeArray {
        node.addChildNode(childNode as SCNNode)
    }
    return node
}

func node(for annotation: Annotation) -> SCNNode? {    
    if annotation.calloutImage == nil {
        // Comment `createLightBulbNode` and add `return nil` to use the default node
        return createLightBulbNode()
    } else {
        let firstColor = UIColor(red: 0.0, green: 99/255.0, blue: 175/255.0, alpha: 1.0)
        return createSphereNode(with: 0.5, firstColor: firstColor, secondColor: UIColor.green)
    }
}
```

Comment: can you provide me your full code

Comment: Hello @Parameswaran V,
Have you got solution of your problem ?

Comment: nope, Now done with mapbox vision api